# Cookies and Functions

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need to create a cookie after all of my form data is filled in by the user. But it also needs to take the user to a Acknowledgement page after the submit button is hit. The code I have is this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


         function validation() 
         {
            var name = document.getElementById ('name').value;
            var address = document.getElementById ('address').value;
            var phone = document.getElementById ('phone').value;
            var email = document.getElementById ('email').value;
            var age = document.getElementById ('age').value;
            var gender = document.getElementById ('gender').value;
            var height = document.getElementById ('height').value;
            var weight = document.getElementById ('weight').value;
            var waist = document.getElementById ('waist').value;
            var medications = document.getElementById ('medications').value;

            if (name=="" || address=="" || phone=="" || email=="" || age=="" || gender==""
                || gender=="" || height=="" || weight=="" || waist=="" || medications=="")
                {
                    alert("Please fill in all Fields.");
                    return false;
                }   
            else
            {
                return true; 
            }
         }

        function WriteCookie() 
        {
            if( document.Myform.name.value == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                cookievalue= escape(document.Myform.name.value) + ";" ;
                document.cookie = "name=" + cookievalue;
                alert("Setting Cookies: " + "name=" + cookievalue);
                return true;
            }   
        }       

        function start()
        {
            validation();
            WriteCookie();
        }   

        start();
    </script>

    </head>
<body>
```

It takes the user to the acknowledgement page but it is not creating my cookie and I am unsure how to fix this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did u tried document.cookie = "name=" + cookievalue; +"path=/"

Answer (score 0):

escape() was depreciated with JavaScript 1.5.

Use encodeURI() instead!

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp